# In Dr. Racket, how to write a Tetration function

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

How would I write a Tetration function in Dr. Racket.
This is my code so far:

```
(define (awesome-tetration k p)
  (cond
    [(= p 1) (expt k p)]
    [else (expt (awesome-tetration k (sub1 p)) (expt k p))]))
```

If I input

```
(awesome-tetration 2 3)
```

My desired output is 2^2^2= 16
However, instead I get:

```
4294967296
```

Why is this happening. Can I get some pointers on what's wrong with my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recursive step is in correct, you're calling `expt` more times than needed. The solution is simpler, you just need to to this:

```
(define (awesome-tetration k p)
  (cond
    [(= p 1) (expt k p)]
    [else (expt k (awesome-tetration k (sub1 p)))]))
```

Now it works:

```
(awesome-tetration 2 3)
=> 16
```